# Flutter API Level 33 Update Error (Already Evaluated)

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, gradle, android-api-33

I have an application currently running and live. Google made it mandatory to update the API level to 33 and later. However, I get various errors, if I solve one problem, another problem arises. I even created a flutter project from scratch and only updated the build gradle files, but I kept getting the same problems. I am writing the gradle information of the application below.

- android/build.gradle
- ext.kotlin.version = "1.6.10"
- dependencies
- classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
- android/app/build.gradle
- compileSdkVersion 33
- targetSdkVersion 33

Onesignal package installed. I also tried without the onesignal package and I still get errors.

Some of the errors I get:

> A problem occured evaluating root project android cannot run project.afterEvaluted(Clouse) when the project is already evaluated
> ext.kotlin.version = <latest.version>

I'm getting two errors at different times, but I couldn't find a solution.

When I make the Kotlin version 1.8.10, I get the evaluated error again.

Answer (score 0):

try ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.20'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).